# SQLite How do I specifically update if i have two or more same data?

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

For better understanding here is my table :

```
//rowid is not my column i wrote it for better understaning

rowid | vacum | manometric | head |    date    | testno
  1   |  15   |      16    |  65  | 23/10/2020 |   1
  2   |  21   |      22    |  45  | 23/10/2020 |   1
  3   |  15   |      23    |  75  | 23/10/2020 |   1
  4   |  74   |      42    |  85  | 23/10/2020 |   1
  5   |  15   |      16    |  68  | 23/10/2020 |   2
  6   |  17   |      16    |  64  | 23/10/2020 |   2
  7   |  19   |      18    |  68  | 23/10/2020 |   2
  8   |  21   |      20    |  67  | 23/10/2020 |   2
```

So i want to update `where date = 23/10/2020 and testno = 2`  second line but we have 4 line in here.

How can I specify this ?

I thought about rowid but it cant work for me cause i cant calculate data's row id its not 4 line everytime.

```
 update mytable 
    set vacum = 18 , manometric = 21, head = 15 
  where date= 23/10/2020 and testno = 2 and rowid = 6;
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the primary key of your table?

Comment: I dont have it, do i need ?

Comment: Hi - are you trying to update every record  "where date = 23/10/2020 and testno = 2"? If not, what are the criteria for identifying which record(s) to update?

Comment: Thanks for answer , yes that's my problem i was searching way to handle that without adding line number. @forpas made it, check his anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
update mytable 
set vacum = 18, 
    manometric = 21, 
    head = 15 
where date = '23/10/2020' and testno = 2
and (
  select count(*) from mytable m 
  where m.date = mytable.date and m.testno = mytable.testno and m.rowid < mytable.rowid
) = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d06ec6592b97d75938000b062a62272c).
Results:

```
> rowid | vacum | manometric | head | date       | testno
> ----: | ----: | ---------: | ---: | :--------- | -----:
>     1 |    15 |         16 |   65 | 23/10/2020 |      1
>     2 |    21 |         22 |   45 | 23/10/2020 |      1
>     3 |    15 |         23 |   75 | 23/10/2020 |      1
>     4 |    74 |         42 |   85 | 23/10/2020 |      1
>     5 |    15 |         16 |   68 | 23/10/2020 |      2
>     6 |    18 |         21 |   15 | 23/10/2020 |      2
>     7 |    19 |         18 |   68 | 23/10/2020 |      2
>     8 |    21 |         20 |   67 | 23/10/2020 |      2
```

Comment: Yeah definitely working, can you explain a little bit (i'm new to sqlite). like what does m in here, creating temporary table ? if does creating new table how can it be diffrent " m.rowid < mytable.rowid " in here

Comment: `m` is the alias of another copy of `mytable`. Inside the subquery m.rowid is the rowid of that 2nd copy and mytable.rowid is the rowid of the table that is updated. So the subquery counts for every row of the table that is updated the number of rows of the table (using the 2nd copy) that have the same date and and testno but less rowid.